# Create a Horizontal Card with CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a horizontal card that will look like this:

[image]

**How can I make it so the "LINK with Icon" divs are evenly spaced out within their own div container?**

I tried using padding on .colum div {} to space them out but it won't.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div clas="colum">
          <div>
          Github
          </div>
          <div>
          Libguides:
          </div>
          <div>
          Instagram:
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="cartoon image">
      </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sourmangos/pen/oNgbMRB)

Comment: you should check out [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). It's a great way to layout items with CSS

Answer (score 2):

Typo in name.

```css
body {
  background: beige;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.colum {
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.colum div {
  background-color: aqua;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.card {
  margin-left: 10px
}

.image {
  background: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="colum">
    <div>
      Github
    </div>
    <div>
      Libguides:
    </div>
    <div>
      Instagram:
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use flexbox to achieve what you want:

```css
.colum {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```